# what is the best way to post Pre defined text on user wall in Facebook through app? - Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

As Share intent is not supporting the text sharing in Facebook. what is the easiest way to just share a string on the wall of the user.

Comment: you have to register your application and use share intent of facebook for do this.

Comment: I did, but still I am not able to share it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not post predefined text on Facebook.

Refer link mentioned below.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill

Answer (score 0):

Facebook does not allow third party apps to post on the wall for security reasons. The only thing that you can do is to embed the Facebook library api in your app and do whatever you want after the user give you the corresponding permissions.

Comment: after that can I able to post predefined text?

Comment: No. You are not allowed to prefill text

Comment: As @WizKid said, You are not allowed to post predefined text. True you can not.